graphviz module not found
Current on my qgis version 3.28.15 i have installed networkx version 2.5 and pygraphviz version 1.11 using the osgeo command. While drawing graph using below code i got the attribution error as module not found.
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph

agraph = to_agraph(self.graph)
agraph.graph_attr.update(self.config["graph_config"])
agraph.draw(out_path, prog=self.config["prog"])



using osgeo command

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753534/networkx-issue-need-to-install-graphviz-pygraphviz-anaconda-2021-11-win10x
